# lxml isn't finding xpath given by Chrome?

Tags: python, html, xml, parsing, lxml

I am trying to get company's industry from the search page of linked in. I get the xpath form Chrome's dev tools but it returns empty brackets. What seems to be the issue here?

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/companies/?keywords=cisco.com')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

industry = tree.xpath('//*[@id="ember3734"]/div/div[1]/p[1]')

print(industry)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the script with selenium and phantomjs because the website use a lot of javascript.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import lxml.html
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities
from pprint import pprint 

desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS.copy()
desired_capabilities['phantomjs.page.customHeaders.User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) ' \
                                                                  'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' \
                                                                  'Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)

username = 'email@email.com'
password = 'password'


# driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com")

driver.find_element_by_id('login-password').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_id('login-email').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_id("login-submit").click()
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/companies/?keywords=cisco.com")
sleep(3)
html = driver.page_source
root = lxml.html.fromstring(html)

reg = re.compile('ember-view\">\s+<h3\s+class=\"search\-result__title\s+Sans\-17px\-black\-85\%\-semibold-dense\">(.*?)<\/h3>')
names =  reg.findall(html)

pprint(names)

driver.quit()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I use any driver or does it have to be PhantomJS?

Comment: I think Phantomjs is better, but is a personal opinion. You will have the same result with firefox or google chrome. But i think phantomjs is lighter.

Comment: @opamp you can use this https://gist.github.com/Wu4m4n/597367d32e443b9fe120f47d78d56bce to install phantomjs

Comment: Thank you! I kind of had problem with that one so I downloaded it and included the path in the webdriver.PhantomJS

Comment: looking closer at this I thought I'd figure it out on my own by I actually needed Company's industry and not name. Is there an easy way to drill down and get the following: Cisco -> Computer Networking?

Comment: This is the answer, for reference: `class=\"subline\-level\-1\s+Sans\-15px\-black\-85\%\s+search\-result__truncate\">(.*?)<\/p>`

Answer (score 0):

I think the page is generated by JavaScript. Since Requests download the page without executing JavaScript you get only the main page/template and not the data you expect.

Try "view the source page" under Chrome to confirm.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Ill try in a bit when I'm on my mac. So how would I go about pulling the data I need in this case?